Magento website hosted on EC2 Instance not connectable after EC2 instance restart
I understand that restarting an EC2 instance tied to a Web server, 2 things will take place.
1.When you restart the instance, the IP address changed. The frontend is now pointing to an outdated address.
2.When you restart the instance, you need to restart the server code inside the instance too.
The website is powered by Adobe Magento, and I am not sure how to restart the server. If the code is written in react or any mainstream framework, I would know how to perform step 2, which is to start the app in the VM. So can anyone kindly point out the steps to launch Magento in the VM?
The content of the EC2 SSH is in https://github.com/MeetArtsSG/magentoV2 .
Additionally, I would also like to know if I can still retain the database after restarting the instance, and where the database is stored.
Thank You in advance.

Try to run the site with your New IP address once. If it was redirected to your host it means you just need to update the IP address for the frontend. Also Please mention if you were using PWA or React module for frontend? Need more details around your setup to figure out what is the actual issue.
